# An Internal gpt script loading with file: protocol

Tags: google-dfp, google-publisher-tag

I am using Google Publisher Tag to display ads inside my game. My game is a web view which is inside an android app. To achieve this I am loading this script `https://securepubads.g.doubleclick.net/tag/js/gpt.js`.

I found out that the above script internally also loads this script `tpc.googlesyndication.com/sodar/sodar2.js` with `file://` protocol. The ad is getting displayed but my game crashes because of this. I tried searching about the cause of this but could not find any solution. Mainly I have question about two things.

1. Why gpt loads `tpc.googlesyndication.com/sodar/sodar2.js` script internally. Can we avoid this if it is not necessary?
2. Why only this script is loading with `file://` protocol and how can we avoid that?

I am trying Google Publisher Tag for the first time so please correct me if I am wrong somewhere.